# Rank the number of employees from high to low for each manager

Tags: sql, oracle

I have searched for similar questions here about such question:
List the number of employees for each manager and rank the number of employees reporting to each managers descending.

But I have not yet found a solution to mine yet.
My code is as below.
Any helps or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
(the question requested to use ranking, but I did not use rank() in my code)

```
SELECT m.first_name, 
       m.last_name as name, 
       count(e.employee_id) as count
FROM RITDB_employee e
INNER JOIN RITDB_manager m ON e.manager = m.employee_id
GROUP BY m.name
ORDER BY m.count
```

Comment: What is incorrect in your code? (besides possibly adding DESC to your ORDER BY)

Comment: Some sample data of the tables and the desired result would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.first_name, 
       m.last_name as name, 
       count(e.employee_id) as count
FROM RITDB_employee e
INNER JOIN RITDB_manager m ON e.manager = m.employee_id
GROUP BY m.name
ORDER BY count(e.employee_id) desc
```

Also a small tip for you, you may better write the full name of tables for your ease to check instead of giving names.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine window functions and `GROUP BY`. The window function will be evaluated **after** grouping. Additionally you need to include `first_name` **and** `last_name` into the `group by` condition:

```
SELECT m.first_name, 
       m.last_name as name, 
       count(*) as count, 
       dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc partition by m.first_name, m.last_name) as rnk
FROM RITDB_employee e
  JOIN RITDB_manager m ON e.manager = m.employee_id
GROUP BY m.last_name, m.first_name
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out. But it gave me "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" error. I am trying to see if I can fix that. Thanks anyways:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're on the right track - the only thing you're missing is ranking the managers by the count of employees you already have. As you've guessed, the `rank` function can do this exactly, although you may prefer to use `dense_rank` if you have ties and want to make sure the ranks are continuous:

```
SELECT   name, cnt, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AK rank_by_employee_num
FROM     (SELECT     m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name as name, 
                     COUNT(e.employee_id) AS cnt
          FROM       RITDB_employee e
          INNER JOIN RITDB_manager m ON e.manager = m.employee_id
          GROUP BY   m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name) t
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```